# Why should we add repositories to sources.list and add keys?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, repository, key

I'm following [this guide](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt) and it says to add repositories to sources.list and add keys. On previous installations I have skipped this step, and the postgresql server has run just fine.

So I'm curious as to what these steps add to the installation process. Is it something to do with version control?

Comment: what Ubuntu release are you running and explain in your post what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: 14.04. Trying to install postgresql. I would have thought that would have been implied by the link

Comment: That link is for GIS Objects "The following describes how to install Postgresql 9.4, PostGIS 2.1, PGAdmin on Ubuntu versions 12.04 and 14.04". If you just want Postgresql use apt-get install postgresql

Comment: I'm aware of that. I'm downloading postgresql and postgis and omitting pgadmin since i have it on desktop. My question is what benefit the parts **Add Respository to sources.list** and **Add Keys** add to the installation process, if `apt-get install postgresql` works just fine without them.

Comment: apt-get install only installs postgresql9.3 and the client-common parts ,not any GIS etc. when you're installing from apt-get read the packages that are being installed and you will see the difference. You're being asked to add the repos for GIS and the subsequent keys that apt-get uses to know where the GIS packages are and has the correct keys